# Open a javafx fxml file in separate window on a button click without duplication

Tags: javafx, fxml

I use the below code to open a javafx fxml file in a different window on a button click event and it works fine. But if I click the same button again while the window opened it will create a duplicate window. Is there a possibly solutions to overcome this problem? Thanks in advance.

```
Parent parent = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("FXMLDocument.fxml"));
Stage stage = new Stage(StageStyle.DECORATED);
stage.setTitle("Title");

stage.setScene(new Scene(parent));
stage.show();
```

Comment: What do you want it to do instead? You are explicitly creating a new window in this code...

Answer (score 1):

I just stumbled upon this old question and figured I might answer it for anyone new to JavaFX or coding in general (I'm bored..).

In the provided code (see below) a new Stage is created every time, meaning that if this is run inside of a method you actually create a new Stage variable every time that the code is run:

```
Stage stage = new Stage(StageStyle.DECORATED);
```

What you could do instead create your Stage variable outside the method so that you either 1. just overwrite it every time or 2. have some "is showing" or a nullcheck or similar to see if a new stage should be created or if the existing one just needs to be shown.

For example:

```
private Stage stage;

private void onOpenNewStageBtnClicked(){
    if(stage == null){
        Parent parent = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("FXMLDocument.fxml"));
        stage = new Stage(StageStyle.DECORATED);
        stage.setTitle("Title");
        stage.setScene(new Scene(parent));
    }
    stage.show();
}
```

Also, what I usually do is I create a Stage factory to avoid a lot of duplicate code and so that I can break out the creation of the stages and the loading of fxmls to other classes than my controller.